# Copy & paste non-ASCII characters to an Emacs window from another window doesn't work correctly

Tags: emacs, unicode, clipboard, emacs23

I work with emacs23 with the iso-8859-1 coding system. I have these lines in my .emacs file:

> `(setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'iso-8859-1)`
>
> `(set-selection-coding-system 'iso-8859-1)`

However, if I try to copy a non-ASCII character from another window and paste it to my emacs window, it doesn't work correctly. For instance, if I try to copy and paste "ì" I get "Ã¬". How can I fix it?

Comment: You should probably switch emacs to UTF-8; `Ã¬` looks like UTF-8 bytes misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1. ISO 8859 is a relict from the previous century, I don't see any reason to keep using it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Karol S, it seems that the best thing to do is switch emacs to UTF-8.